# Piping a string to a scanf automatically ends a system("/bin/sh") in C

Tags: c, bash, pipe

I had a hard time to find a good title, feel free to edit it if you have a better idea!

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char name[20];

    scanf("%24s",name);
    printf("name: %s\n",name);
    system("/bin/sh");

    return 0;
}
```

It works quite well if I launch it and then type my name:

```
user@linux:~$ ./program 
J.Doe
name: J.Doe
$
```

As you can see, I get my shell. However, if I pipe my name, I won't get access to the shell:

```
user@linux:~$ echo "J.Doe" | ./program 
name: J.Doe
user@linux:~$
```

My question is, what's happening here exactly? Why is the shell closed? How would I be able to pipe some command, or get the prompt back?

I suppose that there is no more data to be sent to the program (because "J.Doe" has already been sent to the `scanf`), but I believed that the shell would hang, waiting indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

When you a line of input to the program, it still runs the shell, but that shell runs out of input and terminates. Its standard input device is inherited from the program.

It's similar to:

```
notbinsh $ echo | /bin/sh
notbinsh $
```

`/bin/sh` finishes executing the null script and terminates.